# How to allow user of certain role to create user only of selected roles?

Tags: 7, users

I have few profiles. One profile per role. I've created few registration paths by [Profile2 Registration Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module.

I have an issue with permissions, for example I want  allow user of role A, to create users of roles A or B, but because Profile2 Registration Path uses 'administer users' permission on it's registration paths, certain role can create users of all roles or none at all. Maybe I missed something, but I'm stuck.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Role Delegation](https://www.drupal.org/project/role_delegation)

> This module allows site administrators to grant some roles the
>   authority to assign selected roles to users, without them needing the
>   administer permissions permission.